Результат работы скрипта Powershell в Ansible
PS-cкрипт запускается с помощью Ansible (awx). В процессе работы в окне cmd идёт процесс работы самого скрипта, затем, по завершению то же самый результат записывается в txt. Как вывести результат в anisble?

А чё, в register ничего не записывается что ли?
